# Attempting to install from Software Center hangs

Tags: software-installation, software-center

software center  won't install. The installation hangs and I am repeatidly asked for authentication which I do and the authentication pop up window appears again after 10 seconds over and over again. New to ubuntu 12.4 as of 2 days ago.

[image]

[this is a screenshot of the authentication popup on install page in software-centre](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3eV38dU3ePddDV0YmRKSWVkb0U/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the error?

Comment: i don-t get an error. the install just runs. it hangs and i repeatidly get the pop up for authentication to install the program over and over again. i-ve tried to take a screen shot but not able to.

Comment: @astrob0t actually on the 2 paid applications that i tried to install the install hangs and i am repeatidly asked for authentication. there are no error messages. It just shows that it is installing but nothing happens. other applications installed fine that were free. like qBittorrent, and skype

Comment: When you buy an application from ubuntu software center, you are redirected to Ubuntu SSO login site where you need to login using your Ubuntu SSO credentials(this is not the PC login credentials :P). You would have to sign up with Ubuntu if you dont have one. You would then receive a mail from canonical confirming the purchase and then the installation would start. Can you confirm if you encountered all the above.

Comment: @astrob0t i've done all of that. logged in and signed up. actually nothing is installing from software center. just hangs. I took a screen shot. how do I attach it to this comment?

Comment: you can edit your question and attach the screenshot there.

Comment: @astrob0t I just uninstalled software-center and reinstalled it and still not working . upon clicking on install it asks for authentication, then a few seconds pass, and it asks for authentication, then it warns of installing from untrusted sources, I say ok, then it asks for authentication again, then again wars of untrusted sources over and over.

Comment: @astrob0t sorry. don't know how to attach screenshot here

Comment: @astrob0t done. see link to screen shot above and edited description

Answer (score 0):

Open up a terminal and run Software Center with debug switch (issue following command),

```
software-center --debug
```

Pay attention to the debug screen for possible cause. Probably you can copy and paste relevant section of the debug screen here.

Comment: didn't work. Still hangs and repeatidly asking for authentication.  also copy and paste isn't working on the terminal window either.

Comment: I reinstalled ubuntu and have same problem again. Software center hangs repeatidly asks for authentication.

Comment: your fix didn't work